# Navigation Drawer does not open

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

In my application I want to use `Navigation Drawer` and `Action Bar` in all Activities. Therefore In MainActivity I had declared them and other activities `extends` from this MainActivity. Now `ActionBar` works fine in Other activities also, But `Navigation drawer` does not opens in  other activities. icon of drawer is visible in other activities but it is not open. If i remove `setContentView` from other `activities` then drawer works perfectly. But after setting `setContentView` it shows only icon but does not open.

**following is my MainActivity code:**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements
    NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
protected NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {

    switch (position) {
    case 1: {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                Test.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        break;
    }
    }

    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    /*FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();*/
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_my_account);
        break;
    case 2:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_my_fav);
        break;
    case 3:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_do);
        break;

    case 4:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_news);
        break;
    case 5:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_dont);
        break;
    case 6:
        mTitle = getString(R.string.title_setting);
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);

    Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.login_btn);  
    //actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#99cc00")));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        ((MainActivity) activity).onSectionAttached(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER));
    }
}

}
```

**my NavigationDrawerFragment code is like:**

```
package com.example.nav3;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the
 * user manually expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ListView mDrawerListView;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated
    // awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState
                .getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

    // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of
    // actions in the action bar.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mDrawerListView = (ListView) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    selectItem(position);
                }
            });
    mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar()
            .getThemedContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
        getString(R.string.title_my_account),
        getString(R.string.title_my_portfolio),
        getString(R.string.title_market_ideas),
        getString(R.string.title_news),
        getString(R.string.title_my_profile),
        getString(R.string.title_setting),}));
    mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);
    return mDrawerListView;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null
            && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation
 * drawer interactions.
 * 
 * @param fragmentId
 *            The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout
 *            The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 */
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer
    // opens
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), /* host Activity */
    mDrawerLayout, /* DrawerLayout object */
    R.drawable.ic_drawer, /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_open, /*
                                     * "open drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close /*
                                     * "close drawer" description for
                                     * accessibility
                                     */
    ) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to
                // prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true)
                        .commit();
            }

            getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls
                                                            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce
    // them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerListView != null) {
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
    }
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar.
    // See also
    // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the
    // action bar.
    if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
        showGlobalContextActionBar();
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_settings) {
        /*Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();*/
        System.out.println("click on setting");
        //return true;
    }

    else if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_refresh)
    {
        System.out.println("click on refresh icon");
    }

    /*if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return true;
    }*/

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to
 * show the global app 'context', rather than just what's in the current
 * screen.
 */
private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
}

private ActionBar getActionBar() {
    return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
}

/**
 * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must
 * implement.
 */
public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    /**
     * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
     */
    void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
}
}
```

**Here is my Test activity which extends MainActivity:**

```
public class Test extends MainActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.out.println("inside Test onCreate ");
    //setContentView(R.layout.test);
}

}
```

activity_main xml is:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using     match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.nav3.MainActivity" >

<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.example.nav3.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

my fragment_navigation_drawer.xml is:

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#023863"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
tools:context="com.example.nav3.NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

And test.xml is simple button contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="110dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here after commenting `setContentView Navigation drawer` works but after setting setContentView layout it only shows icon but does not open. Why is it so? What wrong in this? Any suggestion will be apprecited. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have DrawerLayout in your test layout?
Could you add your main layout and test layout

Comment: I had added layout in question above. I dont have DrawerLayout in test.xml

Comment: So you have to add DrawerLayout to your layout

Comment: Can you show me code where to add DrawerLayout with some textview and button in text.xml. And one more thing does that mean I have to add this in every activities xml file? Thanks